# Erase columns where duplicated rows exist, in groups. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to show columns which have only duplicated rows inside, in `Name` groups
I cannot remove/drop columns for one groupo because for other this specific column could be usefull.
So when in specific column will be duplicates i need to make this column empty (replace with np.nan for example)

my df:

```
Name,B,C,D
Adam,20,dog,cat
Adam,20,cat,elephant
Katie,21,cat,cat
Katie,21,cat,dog
Brody,22,dog,dog
Brody,21,cat,dog
```

expected output:

```
#grouping by Name, always two Names are same, not less not more.
Name,B,C,D
Adam,np.nan,dog,cat
Adam,np.nan,cat,elephant
Katie,np.nan,np.nan,cat
Katie,np.nan,np.nan,dog
Brody,22,dog,np.nan
Brody,21,cat,np.nan
```

I know I should use `groupby()` function and `duplicated()`
but I dont know how this approach should looks like

```
output=df[df.duplicated(keep=False)].groupby('Name')
output=output.replace({True:'np.nan'},regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with lambda function and [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) for replace:

```
df = df.set_index('Name')
output=df.mask(df.groupby('Name').transform(lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False))).reset_index()
print (output)
    Name     B    C         D
0   Adam   NaN  dog       cat
1   Adam   NaN  cat  elephant
2  Katie   NaN  NaN       cat
3  Katie   NaN  NaN       dog
4  Brody  22.0  dog       NaN
5  Brody  21.0  cat       NaN
```

Comment: you are my Yoda, i want to be like you :D